# Unable to access .out text files in godaddy server?

Tags: php, http-headers, godaddy-api

In my php website, I am reading data from text files with .out extension. It was working fine on my localhost. But, when I uploaded the site to godaddy linux hosting. It stopped working. It is giving 500 error when I tried to inspect the network request. Also, it triggered the following error: Ensure CORS response header values are valid

Do I need to enable a certain php plugin to make it work?

my code sample:

```
$file = 'file.out';


// the following line prevents the browser from parsing this as HTML.
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

// get the file contents, assuming the file to be readable (and exist)
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
// escape special characters in the query
$txt = explode("\n",$contents);

$counter = 0;
foreach($txt as $key => $line){
    $subbedString = substr($line,2,6);

   // $searchfor = '0123456';
    //echo strpos($subbedString,$searchfor); 
    if(strpos($subbedString,$searchfor) === 0){
        $matches[$key] = $searchfor;
        
          echo  "<p>" . $matches[$key] . "</p>";
          
                  $counter += 1;
                  if($counter==10) break;
         
    }
```

Comment: do you use any frameworks ?

Comment: not in particular.

Comment: We can't just figure out the issue without more details, could you provide use with a part of your code how do try to access your files ?!

Comment: sure, one moment please.

Comment: could you provide us where your files located ?

Comment: Are you able to access the file at all from the browser? try accessing it and create a .txt file on the same dir and try accessing it also... can you? perhaps you are blocking access with .htaccess ....

Comment: I am able to access it directly by typing in the url; but, unable to read it on the webserver

Comment: @Shlomtzion fyi, it is a spice file.

Comment: @Shlomtzion while inspecting the page it triggered the following error: Ensure CORS response header values are valid

Comment: If the files are in the same folder as the php script calling them you shouldn't have any CORS problems... can you read a .txt file ? I know it's a funny question but try it... try and read a .txt file the same way... CORS is for Cross Origin .. .if your files are located in the same dir of the PHP script you should have problems with CORS...